# Не выводятся inline кнопки в боте. Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Бот должен брать информацию из БД и выводить ее в кнопках. Текст и callback_data обязательно должен содержать смайлы. В переменной type у меня хранится инфа со смайлами. Вот мой код:

```
    result = db.Clients.select_product_for_sale()

    if result:

        button_list = []
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        for row in result:

            city = row[0]
            type = row[1]
            place = row[2]
            price = row[3]

            button_text = f'{type} - {price} $' 
            callback_text = f'{type} {city} {place} {price}'

            button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text=button_text, callback_data=f"product_name {callback_text}"))

        button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text="⬅️ Назад", callback_data=f"button5"))
        keyboard.add(*button_list)

        await bot.send_message(user_id, "Что вас интересует?", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Проблема в том, что callback_data не хочет обрабатывать данные со смайлами, я попробовал в callback_data убрать type и оставить type в text и все вывелось без проблем, но мне обязательно нужна инфа со смайлами в callback, может возможно это как-то исправить ?

Выскакивает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще оно странно работает... Если смайлы местами поменяю или увеличу их кол-во на 1 больше, то работает и наоборот..

Comment: Так же я попробовал просто текст без смайлов и пробелов, если там много букв, например 20 то та же ошибка, если меньше, то все выводится, хотя ограничение для переменной type в БД у меня 255 символов

Comment: Теперь я попробовал исключительно писать числа.. и их можно ставить сколько угодно, в отличие от букв. Честно я не понимаю, обьясните если у кого-то есть хоть малейшие понятия. 
   Может проблема в типе данных ? В таблице у столбца type тип данных varchar(255)

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, у callback_data есть ограничение в 64 байта, у меня там помимо type хранится еще куча переменных, поэтому и происходили ошибки